# Purge postgresql database as it was new

Tags: sql, database, scripting, postgresql

I have created a PostgreSQL database dump using `psql`.

Now I want to restore this backup from the file:

```
psql -d thesamename -f /my/backup/file
```

But I get errors that the data already exists.

Is there any command to delete everything from the database to bring it to *just created* state, except dropping and creating once again?
(I don't want to set up owner, tablescpace etc. once again)

Maybe some way to overwrite the database with the one from the backup file? (the backup file is from another database server)

Comment: Sounds like you just need to use TRUNCATE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgrestore.html

Have a look specifically at the `-c` option for these scripts.

Comment: Oh, Thanks. I was looking the `--clean` option in `psql` instead of `pg_dump`

Answer (score 2):

You can drop the `public` schema of your database and re create it after :

```
DROP SCHEMA PUBLIC CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA PUBLIC AUTHORIZATION postgres;
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO public;
```

Hope it helps…

Answer (score 1):

you can manipulate it as you want..and you want only dumping of data.once you will start to dumping data schema file will generate automatically.and no need to drop old data.it will overlap with new data over existing data.

You can go through this link for more clarification..

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/app-pgdump.html

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/app-pgrestore.html

You can use

`GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO public;`